# catkin_make works but catkin build fails

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with a complex software where I have to make some changes.
In order to build it, I was instructed to use catkin_make, which was (and is) working well.
Now I have to use MAVROS, and [the guide](https://dev.px4.io/en/ros/mavros_installation.html) says to use catkin build instead.

However, I am unable to do so, it keeps giving a lot of errors, most of them about not found header files.

Why is this happening? shouldn't both methods build fine? (or fail both)

Is it possible to work with MAVROS with catkin_make?

(I know you can't work with both at the same time, so before switching I am doing catkin clean --all)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277109/catkin_make-works-but-catkin-build-fails/) by [danividanivi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32522/danividanivi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, it would be easier to help if you would post the error Output...

`catkin build` is more strict in some ways than `catkin_make`. E.g. it is more sensitive to having dependencies specified correctly. I guess (as there is no error output) this is your Problem.

About whether you can bild MAVROS with `catkin_make`, I'd like to cite the guide you linked to:

> Note that while the package can be
> built using catkin_make the prefered
> method is using catkin_tools as it is
> a more versatile and "friendly" build
> tool.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to what @mig said, checkout [@joq's answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/243192/catkin_make-vs-catkin-build/?answer=243360#post-id-243360) in which he states *not* to mix `catkin_make` and `catkin build`. Here's the body of his answer.

> Do not combine the two build tools in the same workspace at the same time. Their build artifacts are incompatible.
>
> If you run `catkin config`, it will tell you which toolset is currently in use. If you wish to switch to `catkin build`, run `catkin clean -bdy` first.

Here's [the `catkin_tools` docs](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2